# How can I record the screen? RecordMyDesktop gives low quality

Tags: software-recommendation, desktop-recording

I used the software RecordMyDesktop with these settings

- zero compression
- capture full in each square
- quality in video and audio 100%

My records have low quality and some parts show in squaters with pixels

[image: low quality desktop image]

How can I get better quality records?

Comment: Try EasyScreenCast!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen you answer is beautifull!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try using **Simple Screen Recorder** for record the desktop screen. It has good enough video quality for me. If you want to install it, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```

Comment: seems like you are using local language that I did not uderstand with that error message, can you translate it to english or use pastebin.com to paste your error message